# How can PHP's finfo::buffer be spoofed?

Tags: php, file

When handling uploaded files `$_FILES['foo']['type']` is not at all reliable. I've found if you change the extension on OS X the 'type' is changed automatically.

Instead consider:

```
$fileInfo = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mimeType = $fileInfo->buffer(file_get_contents($_FILES['foo']['tmp_name']));
$mimeType = explode(';', $mimeType);
```

Now, if I rename a PHP script to .jpg and upload it (on OS X 10.10) `$_FILES['foo']['type']` = `image/jpeg` and  `$mimeType` = `text/x-php`.

The file type can easily be changed but how can PHP's finfo::buffer be spoofed? What is the difference between what PHP checked for `$_FILES['foo']['type']` and `finfo(FILEINFO_MIME)`?

Answer (score 4):

PHP doesn't check anything in the `$_FILES` type; when uploading a file, the sending *browser* is sending meta data of what it thinks the file type is. `$_FILES['file']['type']` simply reflects this value uploaded by the browser. Obviously, anyone can spoof this at will.

Finfo uses the [*magic* database](http://www.magicdb.org), which is simply a collection of identifying characteristics of file types. I.e., all JPEG files have a characteristic header, all ZIP files start a certain way, this file type has these number of leading bytes, that file type has those kinds of trailing bytes etc. etc. This is harder to spoof, if you actually want to produce a valid file of a certain type, but by no means impossible.

Answer (score 3):

`$_FILES` gets it's type from the Content-Type header of the mime part that contains the file. That part is created by whatever sends the file, usually a browser which will guess the type based on the file extension.

The fileinfo extension, on the other hand, relies on the magic_open library. If I remember correctly, magic_open will check multiple attributes of the file, including file headers to determine the mimetype. Try embedding php in an html file. I believe, since the file header is `<!DOCTYPE html>` it will determine `text/html` is the mime type.

Comment: Thanks so for a successful spoof would you need to allow text/html files to be uploaded and then also allow the file to be executed in a folder that allows PHP files to run? If you're just allowing images, for example, is getting PHP code in there not possible using finfo?